# WIX installer : Adding POS as a prerequisite

Tags: installation, wix, point-of-sale, pos-for-.net

I wish to install [Microsoft POS (Point of service)](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=eaae202a-0fcc-406a-8fde-35713d7841ca&displaylang=en) with my installer, after installing .net fx, sql server compact edition, etc.

I am willing to supply the downloaded exe with installer (no need to get it from the web).

I've found this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/pointofservice/archive/2008/06/20/installing-pos-for-net-from-your-installer.aspx). The article in the link indicate that you need to call setup with some parameters.
But I've got no clue how to do this Wix wise. Second I am not sure that it is the right way do it as well. (maybe a merge module is needed?)

Anybody knows?

Answer (score 4):

Wix produces MSI files, and you cannot launch a setup program from inside an MSI. If you find a merge module for POS you can included it in your Wix. Otherwise you'll have to use a bootstrapper to install POS first and then launch your MSI (like [DotNetInstaller](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotNetInstaller.aspx)).

Comment: Yes, it creates an MSI - but you can still call external applications, even those are only EXE's. Granted, a merge module would be the preferred way to go, but if only an EXE is available, that can be called via a custom action, too!

Comment: Not if that EXE is actually a bootstrapper that will in turn invoke an MSI. My understanding was that the POS installer was in fact a bootstrapper... but, I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah yes - good point. If the POS install is indeed an MSI, then you'd have to have a merge module

Comment: +1 for DotNetInstaller link, I've been looking for a good replacement for msbuild's GenerateBootstrapper task.

Comment: but POS is not a Merged Module, as far I can find around the web. what can I do? convert the MSI to msm?

Comment: I've seen tools to convert MSM to MSI, but not the other way around.
I think you'll need a bootstrapper after all.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently struggled with this problem while trying to provide POS for .NET in a WiX bootstrapper.  Out of the box the POS for .NET executable is not very helpful, especially when trying to provide it as a silent install from another installer.  I found the best way to work around this was to provide POS for .NET in a more friendly custom self-extracting executable. This is the solution that worked for me:

1. Run the POS for .NET executable and extract the files to a local directory.
2. Highlight all files and folders in the unzipped directory and, using WinRAR, click "Add to archive..."
3. In the window that pops up click browse to select where your output file will save to and change the Archive Name to something more friendly (optional).
4. Click "Create SFX Archive" under the Archiving Options section; click OK and an executable file will be generated in your specified location.
5. Right-Click on your new executable and choose "Open with WinRAR".
6. Click on the SFX icon at the top and then click "Advanced SFX Options".
7. Under the Setup tab go to "Run after Extraction" and enter:

> Setup.exe /ADDLOCAL Runtime,Posdm
>
> Go the "Modes" tab and make sure "Unpack to temporary folder" is checked, and that "Hide all" is selected under "Silent Mode"
>
> Click OK twice and WinRAR will add your settings to the executable file.
>
> Following the above steps will allow you to package POS for .NET in a "bootstrapper-friendly" way and it can now be included as an ExePackage element in your bundle that will be installed silently.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get a merge module (which would be the preferred solution, if the item is made available by the publisher), you can include an EXE with the installation and then execute it during your WiX install as a custom action.

From the [excellent tutorial on WiX](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/) at Tramontana, here's a [page on custom actions](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson3.php#3.2) and how to set them up - you basically need to define a `<CustomAction>` element in your WiX file and specify what to do when it's executed:

```
<CustomAction Id='LaunchFile' FileKey='FoobarEXE' ExeCommand='' Return='asyncNoWait' />
```

This will launch a file that you just installed as part of your app and that is referenced in your WiX script as `FoobarEXE`.

```
<CustomAction Id='LaunchFile' BinaryKey='FoobarEXE' ExeCommand='' Return='asyncNoWait' />
```

This would reference a binary file (e.g. an EXE), that you included in your WiX installation package (MSI or CAB), but that's not been installed as part of the installation, and that's been extracted as a binary file.

Once you know what you'll do, you need to define when in the sequence of installation steps, this custom action should be executed:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  ...
  <Custom Action='LaunchFile' After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Here, the custom action called `LaunchFile` will be executed after the installation has finalized, but only, if it was determined that the app had not been installed yet.

So, I guess, you should be able to do what you're striving to do with a Custom Action in WiX - see the [WiX 2.0 documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/authoring_custom_actions.htm) and [Steven Bone's blog post series](http://bonemanblog.blogspot.com/2005/10/custom-action-tutorial-part-i-custom.html) for additional info.

Hope this helps!

Marc

Comment: You cannot use windows installer while it is already running. This is such a case: the POS installer is an exe wrapper that invokes windows installer, so you cannot use the exe as a custom action during another installation.

Answer (score 0):

You an use dotnetinstaller, the attached is a sample xml file.

Run InstallerEditor.exe and open the sample xml file, modify it to suit your use, then run InstallerLinker.exe like this:
InstallerLinker.exe /Configuration:"c:\path\to\your\prod.xml" /Output:"c:\work\
setup.exe" /t:"%DOTNETINSTALLER%\Bin\dotNetInstaller.exe" /v

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configurations lcid_type="UserExe" show_language_selector="False" language_selector_title="" language_selector_ok="OK" language_selector_cancel="Cancel" configuration_no_match_message="" ui_level="full" fileversion="" productversion="" log_enabled="True" log_file="#APPPATH\YourPackageInstallLog.txt">
  <schema version="1.10.1525.0" generator="dotNetInstaller InstallerEditor" />
  <fileattributes>
    <fileattribute name="FileDescription" value="YourPackage Installer" />
    <fileattribute name="CompanyName" value="MyCompany Design" />
    <fileattribute name="FileVersion" value="%RESOLVEVERSION%" />
  </fileattributes>
  <configuration dialog_caption="YourPackage Installer" dialog_message="In order to install YourPackage you must install these components:" dialog_message_uninstall="" dialog_bitmap="#APPPATH\banner.bmp" skip_caption="Skip" install_caption="Install" uninstall_caption="Uninstall" cancel_caption="Close" status_installed=" (Installed)" status_notinstalled="" failed_exec_command_continue="Failed to install %s. Continue with others components?" installation_completed="YourPackage installed successfully!" uninstallation_completed="YourPackage uninstalled successfully!" installation_none="YourPackage is already installed!" uninstallation_none="YourPackage is not installed!" installing_component_wait="Installing %s. Wait, this operation could take some time ..." uninstalling_component_wait="Uninstalling %s. Wait, this operation could take some time ..." reboot_required="To continue the installation you must restart your computer. Restart now?" must_reboot_required="False" dialog_otherinfo_caption="" dialog_otherinfo_link="" complete_command="" complete_command_silent="" complete_command_basic="" wait_for_complete_command="True" auto_close_if_installed="True" auto_close_on_error="False" reload_on_error="True" dialog_show_installed="True" dialog_show_uninstalled="True" dialog_show_required="True" cab_dialog_message="%s" cab_cancelled_message="" cab_dialog_caption="" cab_path="#TEMPPATH\#GUID" cab_path_autodelete="True" dialog_default_button="cancel" dialog_position="" dialog_components_list_position="" dialog_message_position="" dialog_bitmap_position="" dialog_otherinfo_link_position="" dialog_osinfo_position="" dialog_install_button_position="" dialog_cancel_button_position="" dialog_skip_button_position="" auto_start="False" auto_continue_on_reboot="False" reboot_cmd="" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True" type="install" lcid_filter="" language_id="" language="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="win7" os_filter_max="win7" processor_architecture_filter="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="True">
    <component package="#CABPATH\%CUDATOOLKITPACKAGE%" cmdparameters="/passive" cmdparameters_silent="/qn" cmdparameters_basic="/qb-" uninstall_package="" uninstall_cmdparameters="/qb-" uninstall_cmdparameters_silent="/qn" uninstall_cmdparameters_basic="/qb-" id="%CUDATOOLKITPACKAGE%" display_name="%CUDATOOLKITPACKAGE%" uninstall_display_name="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="win7" os_filter_max="win7" os_filter_lcid="" type="msi" installcompletemessage="" uninstallcompletemessage="" mustreboot="False" reboot_required="" must_reboot_required="False" failed_exec_command_continue="" allow_continue_on_error="True" default_continue_on_error="False" required_install="False" required_uninstall="False" selected_install="True" selected_uninstall="False" note="" processor_architecture_filter="x64" status_installed="" status_notinstalled="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="False" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True">
      <embedfile sourcefilepath="..\..\..\Prereqs\%CUDATOOLKITPACKAGE%" targetfilepath="%CUDATOOLKITPACKAGE%" />
      <installedcheck path="SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA" fieldname="VersionsInstalled" fieldvalue="%CUDATOOLKITVERSION%" defaultvalue="False" fieldtype="REG_MULTI_SZ" comparison="contains" rootkey="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" wowoption="WOW64_64" type="check_registry_value" description="Installed Check" />
    </component>
    <component executable="#CABPATH\%POSTGRESQLPACKAGE%" executable_silent="" executable_basic="" install_directory="" responsefile_source="" responsefile_target="" responsefile_format="none" uninstall_executable="" uninstall_executable_silent="" uninstall_executable_basic="" uninstall_responsefile_source="" uninstall_responsefile_target="" returncodes_success="" returncodes_reboot="" exeparameters="--mode unattended --unattendedmodeui minimal --servicepassword YourProduct --superpassword YourProduct --superaccount postgres --serviceaccount postgres --debuglevel 4" exeparameters_basic="" exeparameters_silent="" uninstall_exeparameters="" uninstall_exeparameters_basic="" uninstall_exeparameters_silent="" id="%POSTGRESQLPACKAGE%" display_name="%POSTGRESQLPACKAGE%" uninstall_display_name="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="win7" os_filter_max="win7" os_filter_lcid="" type="exe" installcompletemessage="" uninstallcompletemessage="" mustreboot="False" reboot_required="" must_reboot_required="False" failed_exec_command_continue="" allow_continue_on_error="True" default_continue_on_error="False" required_install="False" required_uninstall="False" selected_install="True" selected_uninstall="False" note="" processor_architecture_filter="x64" status_installed="" status_notinstalled="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="False" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True">
      <embedfile sourcefilepath="..\..\..\Prereqs\%POSTGRESQLPACKAGE%" targetfilepath="%POSTGRESQLPACKAGE%" />
      <installedcheck path="SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.0" fieldname="Version" fieldvalue="%POSTGRESQLVERSION%" defaultvalue="False" fieldtype="REG_SZ" comparison="version_ge" rootkey="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" wowoption="WOW64_64" type="check_registry_value" description="Installed Check" />
    </component>
    <component executable="#CABPATH\vcredist_x64.exe" executable_silent="" executable_basic="" install_directory="" responsefile_source="" responsefile_target="" responsefile_format="none" uninstall_executable="" uninstall_executable_silent="" uninstall_executable_basic="" uninstall_responsefile_source="" uninstall_responsefile_target="" returncodes_success="" returncodes_reboot="" exeparameters="/passive" exeparameters_basic="" exeparameters_silent="" uninstall_exeparameters="" uninstall_exeparameters_basic="" uninstall_exeparameters_silent="" id="vcredist_x64.exe" display_name="vcredist_x64.exe" uninstall_display_name="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="win7" os_filter_max="win7" os_filter_lcid="" type="exe" installcompletemessage="" uninstallcompletemessage="" mustreboot="False" reboot_required="" must_reboot_required="False" failed_exec_command_continue="" allow_continue_on_error="True" default_continue_on_error="False" required_install="False" required_uninstall="False" selected_install="True" selected_uninstall="False" note="" processor_architecture_filter="" status_installed="" status_notinstalled="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="False" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True">
      <embedfile sourcefilepath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\vcredist_x64\vcredist_x64.exe" targetfilepath="vcredist_x64.exe" />
      <installedcheck path="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x64" fieldname="Installed" fieldvalue="1" defaultvalue="False" fieldtype="REG_DWORD" comparison="match" rootkey="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" wowoption="WOW64_64" type="check_registry_value" description="Installed Check" />
    </component>
    <component executable="#CABPATH\%QUICKTIMEPACKAGE%" executable_silent="" executable_basic="" install_directory="" responsefile_source="" responsefile_target="" responsefile_format="none" uninstall_executable="" uninstall_executable_silent="" uninstall_executable_basic="" uninstall_responsefile_source="" uninstall_responsefile_target="" returncodes_success="" returncodes_reboot="" exeparameters="/passive" exeparameters_basic="" exeparameters_silent="" uninstall_exeparameters="" uninstall_exeparameters_basic="" uninstall_exeparameters_silent="" id="%QUICKTIMEPACKAGE%" display_name="%QUICKTIMEPACKAGE%" uninstall_display_name="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="win7" os_filter_max="win7" os_filter_lcid="" type="exe" installcompletemessage="" uninstallcompletemessage="" mustreboot="False" reboot_required="" must_reboot_required="False" failed_exec_command_continue="" allow_continue_on_error="True" default_continue_on_error="False" required_install="False" required_uninstall="False" selected_install="True" selected_uninstall="False" note="" processor_architecture_filter="" status_installed="" status_notinstalled="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="False" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True">
      <embedfile sourcefilepath="..\..\..\Prereqs\%QUICKTIMEPACKAGE%" targetfilepath="%QUICKTIMEPACKAGE%" />
      <installedcheck path="SOFTWARE\Apple Computer, Inc.\QuickTime" fieldname="Version" fieldvalue="%QUICKTIMEVERSION%" defaultvalue="False" fieldtype="REG_DWORD" comparison="version_ge" rootkey="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" wowoption="WOW64_32" type="check_registry_value" description="Installed Check" />
    </component>
    <component package="#CABPATH\YourPackageInstaller.msi" cmdparameters="" cmdparameters_silent="/qn" cmdparameters_basic="/qb-" uninstall_package="" uninstall_cmdparameters="/qb-" uninstall_cmdparameters_silent="/qn" uninstall_cmdparameters_basic="/qb-" id="YourPackageInstaller.msi" display_name="YourPackageInstaller.msi" uninstall_display_name="" os_filter="" os_filter_min="win7" os_filter_max="win7" os_filter_lcid="" type="msi" installcompletemessage="" uninstallcompletemessage="" mustreboot="False" reboot_required="" must_reboot_required="False" failed_exec_command_continue="" allow_continue_on_error="False" default_continue_on_error="False" required_install="True" required_uninstall="True" selected_install="True" selected_uninstall="True" note="" processor_architecture_filter="x64" status_installed="" status_notinstalled="" supports_install="True" supports_uninstall="True" show_progress_dialog="True" show_cab_dialog="True">
      <embedfile sourcefilepath="YourPackageInstaller.msi" targetfilepath="YourPackageInstaller.msi" />
      <installedcheck path="SOFTWARE\MyCompany Design\YourProduct YourPackage" fieldname="Version" fieldvalue="%YOURVERSION%" defaultvalue="False" fieldtype="REG_SZ" comparison="version_ge" rootkey="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" wowoption="WOW64_64" type="check_registry_value" description="Installed Check" />
    </component>
  </configuration>
</configurations>
```